# Ubuntu 14 to 15 upgrade broken but now fixed, or is it

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

When upgrading from Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 LTS to 15.04 I ran into about 8 errors and got a broken installation that despite saying it couldn't upgrade was 15.04. The background was gone and a few things are off but after using:

sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-broken
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade

I seem to be back in order. How do I know if I am still running a broken OS? Just because it appears to be functional, does not mean that something is broken. I'll be learning a lot of new things and now every time I troubleshoot, the dodgy upgrade will be a cause I can't disprove. How do I verify? Do I wipe my drive and start again?

Comment: As all errors are not created equal, do you happen to have the 8 errors? Your instinct is good but the specific packages are where the real details begin. Knowing which packages will help you begin to narrow your focus. Doing a clean install is usually safer than an upgrade. LTS to LTS upgrades (like 14.04 to 16.04) are much, much more tested. You will find more details about them. Also current releases like 15.10 will have more current information available in IRC freenode channels like #Ubuntu or your state/country LoCo channel.

Comment: Thanks Grant.  I do not have the errors but I believe they related to dropped connection. I've done more updating since the initial post and I have upgraded to 15.10 from 15.04. With that upgrade I'm more confident my system is stable, what do you think? Also, I wasn't aware we were up to 16.04 LTS. By the looks of it its April 2016.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with your system that is the best thing. Most failures leave clues so I would not be unnecessarily concerned.